# How to show up a new field in a django Model Serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created a different model serilizers like LocationDetailSerializer, ListingDetialSerializer, ..so on.
Each of their models share a OneToOne Relationship with a PropertySerializer's Model.

Property Model:

```
class Property(models.Model):

# ? Relationships

user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

# ? Fields
property_unique_hash_id = models.UUIDField(
    default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
)
.
.
.
.

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "Property " + str(self.pk)
```

ListingDetial Model:

```
class ListingDetial(models.Model):

# ? Relationships
property = models.OneToOneField("properties.Property", 
           on_delete=models.CASCADE)


listing_property_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    choices=choices.LISTING_PROPERTY_TYPE,
    default=choices.LISTING_PROPERTY_TYPE.single_family_detached,
)
.
.
.
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "Listing Detail" + str(self.pk)
```

PropertySerializer:

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

# location_detail = LocationDetailSerializer()
# listing_detial = ListingDetialSerializer()
.
.
.
.
.
class Meta:
    model = Property
    fields = "__all__"
```

In **PropertySerializer** I also want fields like : location_detail, listing_details..so that it can be passed with views.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Add your models

Comment: @JPG Models Added

Comment: Hello, your question is not very clear, where does the location_detail && listing_details come from in your models ? What are LocationDetailSerializer && LocationDetailSerializer?

Comment: @BriseBalloches thanks for responding, 
Actually  I have broken down the big Property Model in to different models.
All of the columns in these Models should actually be the part of Property Model.
I thought creating different Models like LocationDetail, etc  will make organizing of fields easy.
Based on these seperate Models Serializers like  LocationDetailSerializer, LocationDetailSerializer are created.
Do you think that breaking down of these model is a good idea? And if yes than how to populate these fields from different Serilizers with a PropertySerializer?

Comment: It's hard to give you a definite answer here. If you think they should be treated as distinct object because you'll manipulate them separetely then yes it's a good design, if not then maybe put it all in the same model. For serializing relationship in DRF, you should first take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ and if that does not help, describe exactly the behaviour of serializer you expect.

Comment: you can explain more details what exactly you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it to work:

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

locationdetail = LocationDetailSerializer()
listingdetial = ListingDetialSerializer()
.
.
class Meta:
    model = Property
    fields = "__all__"
```

This will give out json in follwing way:

```
{
"id": 3,
"locationdetail": {
    "id": 3,
    "property": 3
    .
    .
    "created": "2021-01-03T01:53:58.987287Z",
    "last_updated": "2021-01-03T01:53:58.987287Z",


},
"listingdetial": {
    "id": 3,
    "property": 3
    .
    .
    "created": "2021-01-03T01:53:58.873135Z",
    "last_updated": "2021-01-03T01:53:58.873135Z",
    
},
}
```